# Define Angular routes to redirect depending on route parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've a very simple Angular routing module which is used to redirect from one route to another one:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'foo',
    redirectTo: 'bar',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class FooRoutingModule { }
```

Now, I want to change the redirection so that it depends on one route parameter (there may be more parameters than this one). So, `foo?para=0` should redirect to `barA`, and `foo?para=1` should redirect to `barB`. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Guards to manipulate routing.

In your case a CanActivate guard should do the job well. Read more about them here : https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
   switch(route.queryParams['para']) {
     case '0' :
        this.router.navigate(['my/url]);
        break;
     case '1':
          ....
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

The "return false;" is very important in your routing, so that the current navigation ( in your case to 'foo') is cancelled.

And in your routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'foo', canActivate:[ MyGuard ]
  }
];
```

Comment: This does not work. In a route definition you need either a component or a redirect. As redirects cannot be guarded, I need to introduce an empty fake component, which isn't a nice solution.

Comment: Please read this article by Victor Savkin, author of Router V3 about component less routes http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes

Comment: Great article! I've found a solution therein, I'll edit your answer.

Comment: I added the empty children, as a route definition requires either a redirect, component, or children definition. And an empty children definition is also fine ;)